# How to query an array inside another array in CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have something similar to the following json structure and I need to search for an specific filename in the Azure CosmosDB data explorer (no matter the position), I have been trying differents ways and also using CROSS APPLY FLATTEN but i cannot get it

```
{
"entityId": "f07256a5-0e60-412a-bcc9-2e1aa66b69f5",
"array1": [
    {
        
        "array2": [
            {
                "fileName": "filename1.pdf",
            },
            {
                "fileName": "filename2.pdf",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Looks like a few other questions are similar and answer this question, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75140973/query-nested-array-in-cosmos-db) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977146/how-to-query-nested-array-with-cosmos-db)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like below,

```
SELECT 
    c.fileName  
FROM d
JOIN f IN d.array1
JOIN c IN f.array2
WHERE c.fileName = "filename1.pdf"
```

Answer (score 3):

This one works for me:

```sql
SELECT c.entityId
FROM c
JOIN one IN c.array1
JOIN two IN one.array2
WHERE two.fileName = 'filename1.pdf'
```

It uses self-joins to create an object for each filename and then filters from those which has the right filename.