# How to filter Azure Cosmos DB child arrays

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following data in Azure Cosmos DB. I want to filter the data based on `between data.date` and `contains employee.full_name`. The following query give undesired result. I really need help to solve this problem. This link [How to query nested array with Cosmos DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977146/how-to-query-nested-array-with-cosmos-db) doesn't seem to fit my expected result.

Cosmos DB data

```json
    {
      "id": "ED-BSC1",
      "data": [
        {
          "date": "2023-05-09",
          "employees": [
            {
              "employee_id": "E3948",
              "full_name": "Donni",
              "loc": "Building F",
              "floor": 5
            },
            {
              "employee_id": "E9372",
              "full_name": "Viona",
              "loc": "Building F",
              "floor": 5
            },
            {
              "employee_id": "E4551",
              "full_name": "Abby",
              "loc": "Building A",
              "floor": 6
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-05-10",
          "employees": [
            {
              "employee_id": "E9032",
              "full_name": "Brian",
              "loc": "Building A",
              "floor": 12
            },
            {
              "employee_id": "E9033",
              "full_name": "Emma",
              "loc": "Building A",
              "floor": 11
            },
            {
              "employee_id": "E9034",
              "full_name": "Emily",
              "loc": "Building A",
              "floor": 11
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-05-11",
          "employees": [
            {
              "employee_id": "E1042",
              "full_name": "Diana",
              "loc": "Building C",
              "floor": 14
            },
            {
              "employee_id": "E5323",
              "full_name": "Dereck",
              "loc": "Building A",
              "floor": 11
            },
            {
              "employee_id": "E9034",
              "full_name": "Emily",
              "loc": "Building B",
              "floor": 19
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I'm using this query to achieve that and it's failed. It still diplays the whole data

```sql
    SELECT
        c.id,
        c.data
    from 
        c 
        join d in c.data 
        join e in d.employees   
    where 
        c.id = 'ED-BSC1' 
        and d.date >= '2023-05-10' 
        and d.date <= '2023-05-11' 
        and e.full_name like '%Em%'
```

Here's the expected result from the query above

```json
    {
      "id": "ED-BSC1",
      "data": [
        {
          "date": "2023-05-10",
          "employees": [
            {
              "employee_id": "E9033",
              "full_name": "Emma",
              "loc": "Building A",
              "floor": 11
            },
            {
              "employee_id": "E9034",
              "full_name": "Emily",
              "loc": "Building A",
              "floor": 11
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-05-11",
          "employees": [
            {
              "employee_id": "E9034",
              "full_name": "Emily",
              "loc": "Building B",
              "floor": 19
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977146/how-to-query-nested-array-with-cosmos-db answer B seems to match your case. Have you tried subquery + `Array(<subquery>)`?

Comment: Have you clicked the link in my question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to filter the data based on `between data.date` and `contains employee.full_name`. The following query give undesired result.

- To get the required solution, I have used array function in nested queries. To know more about array function please refer the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/subquery#array-expression).
- In the first query, I filtered with name and then filtered the output of the first query with dates, as mentioned in the above requirement.
- Below is the Query:

```
SELECT c.id,
ARRAY(
        SELECT VALUE 
        {
            "date": d.date,
            "employees": ARRAY(               
                SELECT VALUE e FROM e IN d.employees                
                WHERE CONTAINS(e.full_name, "Em")
            )
        }
        
        FROM d IN c.data WHERE d.date >= '2023-05-10' AND d.date <= '2023-05-11'          
        
    ) AS data FROM c WHERE c.id = 'ED-BSC1'
```

**Below is the desired result :**

```
[
    {
        "id": "ED-BSC1",
        "data": [
            {
                "date": "2023-05-10",
                "employees": [
                    {
                        "employee_id": "E9033",
                        "full_name": "Emma",
                        "loc": "Building A",
                        "floor": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "employee_id": "E9034",
                        "full_name": "Emily",
                        "loc": "Building A",
                        "floor": 11
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-05-11",
                "employees": [
                    {
                        "employee_id": "E9034",
                        "full_name": "Emily",
                        "loc": "Building B",
                        "floor": 19
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

- [Here](https://i.imgur.com/0evGSu3.png) is the screenshot of the query run along with output in Cosmos DB.